# Unable to fetch tasks from all the task lists in SharePoint 2013 using CAML

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

following is my Query:-

```
SPSiteDataQuery oQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                oQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"171\" />";
                oQuery.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                                     "<Eq>",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Status' />",
                                        "<Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value>",
                                     "</Eq>",  
                               "</Where>");
                oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +  /* Title is LastName column </Today>*/
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkTitle\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"Body\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"NewStarter\"/>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>";
                oQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
```

I have 6 tasks lists in my SharePoint site. I can see tasks with status as 'Not Started' in the 6 task lists. However, in Visual Studio 2012, when I use CAML to query the tasks lists using ID as 171, I cannot see any tasks... Am I doing something wrong in my query?

Comment: 171 is for TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy. Are you sure your lists are of this type. For Tasks list the number is 107

Comment: I tried 107, this does not return any results (0 results). However, using 171 I get the items of the workflow task list. But not other task lists...

Comment: First and foremost, you need to be sure which lists to search.

Comment: There is a suspicious NewStarter field in your query. Mark it as Nullable and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debuged the code and checked which site was used to fetch the tasklist items from..

And it was referring to another site, now I have hardcoded the siteURL. I was using RootWeb[0] so guess it was looking up some parent site..

Answer (score 2):

Apart from knowing which list template to search, modify the query and add Nullable attribute for empty values

```
"<FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
```

> Note that setting the Nullable attribute to TRUE causes an
>   empty value to be returned for lists that do not include the
>   FirstName column. The default is to skip a list that does not
>   include the column.

See here for complete reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms409088.aspx

Comment: +1, **NewStarter** field seems to be a custom one. Maybe only one list includes this field, and the others don't. In this case, marking the field as Nullable should help.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the server template to 107.If you change the webs scope to site collection, the query would be faster too.See below example.

```
SPSiteDataQuery dataQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                        dataQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
                        dataQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"107\" MaxListLimit=\"0\"/>";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<ProjectProperty Name=\"Title\" />";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\" />";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>";

                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\"Priority\"/>";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\"Status\"/>";
                        dataQuery.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name=\"PercentComplete\"/>";

                        dataQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + Constants.ColNameStartDate + "' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";
                        dataQuery.Query += "<Where>" +
                           "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" /><Value Type=\"User\">" + currentuser + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                                "<Neq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Completed</Value></Neq>" +
                                              "</And>" +
                                               "</Where>";



                        DataTable dtWorkflowTask = web.GetSiteData(dataQuery);
```